# If two views have equal weight but the available space is "odd", which view get the "remainder"? (or do the vie

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="11dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_text"
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/first_layout"            
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_text"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/second_layout"     
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_text"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which layout gets the 11th pixel?  (assuming 1px = 1dp)
Is it based on the order they are written, drawn, other?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to show in your Layout, this is horizontal or vertical?